# Bootstrap modal page issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

When i click on modal close button it disappears but when i click on background it not only disappears but also disable the modal button plus all the links on the page.

What could be the possible reason?

Asp.net code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Modal Popup" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" OnClick="Button3_onClick" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender_Error" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button3"
    PopupControlID="MyPanel_Error" Enabled="True" CancelControlID="CloseError_btn"
    DynamicServicePath="">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="MyPanel_Error" runat="server">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                        Grid View in popup panel</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" CssClass="table" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="COUNTRY_ID" HeaderText="Country ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="COUNTRY_ID" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="COUNTRY1" HeaderText="Country" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="COUNTRY1" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" runat="server" ContextTypeName="PerformanceAppraisalSystem.DataModel.PMSDataContext"
                                EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="COUNTRY1" Select="new (COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY1)" TableName="COUNTRies"
                                Where="COUNTRY_ID &lt; @COUNTRY_ID">
                                <WhereParameters>
                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="14" Name="COUNTRY_ID" Type="Int64" />
                                </WhereParameters>
                            </asp:LinqDataSource>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="CloseError_btn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Post your code and/or a [Bootply](http://bootply.com)

Comment: When I've seen this issue before, the problem is usually that there's transparent padding laying on top of the links. Try using the developer tools in your browser to check those links and see if the modal overlay still exists, even after the modal is dismissed.